# How can I backup Installed chrome add-ons and restore

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

In my Google Chrome browser **"[Spell checker and Grammar checker by Ginger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-and-grammar/kdfieneakcjfaiglcfcgkidlkmlijjnh)"** add-ons installed.

It's very important add-on for me, to improve and correct spelling as well as grammar.

But now Author has been deleted this Add-on.
How can I backup installed add-on. So I'll restore this add-on in future.

Answer (score 0):

All your Google Chrome Extensions (Add-ons) can be found on your local computer in the %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions folder. (Windows)

[On linux, Chrome extensions are stored in:~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/]

All you have to do is make a copy of this folder and it's contents on an USB device or on a seperate folder on your hard disk.

To restore your Extensions copy everything back to this very same folder.

You should be careful however and be aware that as Google keeps updating Chrome your older extensions may lose compatibility.

Here's a [link](http://www.trishtech.com/2014/05/backup-restore-google-chrome-extensions-manually/) for a bit more thorough description but it's really simple so I guess it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: My environment is a Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: On linux, Chrome extensions are stored in: 
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/

[+Added to the answer as well]

Comment: In case it's Chromium then it should be ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions

Comment: This is likely not backing up any configuration (for example custom dictionary for the OP's example).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Backup and Restore Google Chrome Offline](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9N0LRCXDW2ZM) to copy Google Chrome data and extension between computers without a Google Account and without Internet.